# Regex to match a URL and insert a directory

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I would like to use regex to match the following:

```
http://www.test.com/example/sometext/
```

and then redirect to:

```
http://www.test.com/uk/example/sometext/
```

where '`example`' is not in a list of reserved words, like `_images`, `_lib`, `_css`, etc.

Comment: Is this for `mod_rewrite` or in a particular language? Might be helpful to edit your question to specify this (and add appropriate tags).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
(http://www.test.com/)((?!(_images|_lib|_css))[^/]+/sometext/)
```

And replace with

```
$1uk/$2
```

Broken down, the juicy buts are:

- `(?!someregex)` = a negative lookahead - ie assert the following input does not match `someregex`
- `(_images|_lib|_css)` = the syntax for regex `OR` logic, just using literals
- `[^/]+` = some characters that aren't a slash